# MongoDB: How to access the parent of the list when using $where

Tags: mongodb

Data sample

```
{
  "Subject": "New thread"
  "Messages": [
    {
      "DateSent": "Mon, 16 May 2011 14:34:17 GMT -04:00",
    },
    {
      "DateSent": "Mon, 16 May 2011 14:59:57 GMT -04:00",
    }
  ],
  "Participants": [
    {
      "UserId": 2,
      "LastReadMessageIndex": 0,
    },
    {
      "UserId": 1,
      "LastReadMessageIndex": 1
    }
  ],
}
```

A thread contains a list of messages and a list of participants. When a participant views a thread, the LastReadMessageIndex gets updated to the length of the Messages.

I want to retrieve the number of threads where there are unread messages for a given participant. I can use the $where operation within my list of participant like this:

```
db.MessageThreads.find( {Participants: {$elemMatch: { UserId: 2, $where: {this.LastReadMessageIndex) < this.**parent**.Messages.length}}} }).count();
```

Is it possible to access the parent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having here is that you're pairing `$elemMatch` and `$where`. In the context of `$where`, the value of `this` should be the document itself. However, it looks like you're saying that `this` is a sub-document.

Here's some sample code that does what you want:

```
unread = function () {
    for (var i in this.Participants) {
        if (this.Participants[i].UserId == 2 &&
            this.Participants[i].LastReadMessageIndex < this.Messages.length) {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

db.MessageThreads.find(unread)
```

The only problem here is that I have hard-coded the `UserId` to `2`. If you're planning to call this from one of the client drivers, you'll have to inject that `2` in the right spot.

If it seems a little "hacky", it is. You're trying to compare sub-documents within a single document and MongoDB is not great at this and your document structure does not make this easy.

You may want to consider:

```
"Participants": {
  "2": { "LastReadMessageIndex": 0 },
  "1": { "LastReadMessageIndex": 1 }
}
```

This changes won't solve the problem entirely, but it does make they query a lot easier:

```
unread = function() { 
  return (this.Participants['2'].LastReadMessageIndex < 
    this.Messages.length);
}
```

If this is an important query, you may want to consider building a Map / Reduce for this process instead.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, changing the structure makes sense and is cleaner.